# Converting result set of a column into those many column names in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

How to divide result set of a Column into multiple columns

Suppose I've a column Quarter and Tenure with values as below for table Sample

```
Quarter|Tenure
Q1     |3
Q2     |3
Q3     |2
Q4     |1
```

So tenure is the number of months served quarterly by an employee.

Now I expect the result set to be the four different tenures fetched quarterly should be in four different columns. Meaning it should show for which quarter how much is the tenure but in 4 different columns.

e.g.

```
Q1_A| Q2_A |Q3_A |Q4_A
3   | 3    |2    |1
```

Comment: Does your table never have more than 4 rows? (Add a few more rows of sample table data, and adjust the expected result accordingly.)

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54418331/edit) your question to give a [MCVE] including details of how you are generating your data because it is not in your question and people are giving answers based on the information you have given in the question and then you turning around and saying that it does not work because of some information everyone else is not party to is not constructive.

Answer (score 0):

You could use DECODE:

```
SELECT SUM(DECODE(quarter,'Q1',tenure,0)) Q1_A,
SUM(DECODE(quarter,'Q2',tenure,0)) Q2_A,
SUM(DECODE(quarter,'Q3',tenure,0)) Q3_A,
SUM(DECODE(quarter,'Q4',tenure,0)) Q4_A
FROM Sample;
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187518/discussion-on-answer-by-virgil-ionescu-converting-result-set-of-a-column-into-th).

Comment: Thank you Virgil for your answer. This helped. Thank you again

Answer (score 0):

Use `PIVOT`:

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name ( Quarter, Tenure ) AS
  SELECT 'Q1', 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Q2', 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Q3', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Q4', 1 FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
PIVOT  ( MAX( Tenure ) FOR Quarter IN (
    'Q1' AS Q1_A,
    'Q2' AS Q2_A,
    'Q3' AS Q3_A,
    'Q4' AS Q4_A
) )
```

**Output**:

```
Q1_A | Q2_A | Q3_A | Q4_A
---: | ---: | ---: | ---:
   3 |    3 |    2 |    1
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=6a08ffeca116319f28531df542bb8b00)*

Comment: Quarter and Tenure are calculated values.

Comment: @user10977675 Not sure what your point is. Can you not just use `WITH table_name ( quarter, tenure ) AS ( <INSERT_YOUR_QUERY_TO_CALCULATE_THE_VALUES_HERE> ) <INSERT_THE_PIVOT_QUERY_HERE>`

Comment: @user10977675 . . . It is only possible to answer the question that you actually ask -- and this answers your question.  If you have a different question, then ask a *new* question.